# Excel Data convert from single row to multiple row

Tags: excel-formula

I have data in excel in following manner.

```
Colname Count
A       5
B       3
C       4
```

I want to convert it into this way.

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   4
A   5
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
C   3
C   4
```

Based on the count i want that data must be converted into rows with increasing order. Please let me know the feasiblity .

Comment: Not so simple with formulas alone. Are you opposed to VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ROW()<B$1+1,"A",IF(AND(ROW()>B$1,ROW()<SUM(B$1:B$2)+1),"B",IF(AND(ROW()>SUM(B$1:B$2),ROW()<SUM(B$1:B$3)+1),"C",""))) in F1 and fill down. In G1, this formula =IF(COUNTA(F1)>0,COUNTIF(F$1:F1,F1),"") and fill down. Letters are in Column A and numbers in Column B. I chose these columns randomly to work a solution. Change to match your actual data, if needed.
```